# $.ajax post, knockout, and web api

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I have a method in a web api controller that is being called from a javascript (knockout) function.

```
    public void SaveEmailTempage(EmailTemplateModel template)
    {
        var x = template.ToString();
    ...
```

the x variable above is only there so I can set a break point in the controller, and it gets hit. The passed in template variable has all of it's attributes always set to null and that is the question - why? I'm not sure what to pass in in the $.ajax call, data parameter.

In the javascript I have this (below). In the data property, I've tried self, this, ko.JS, ko.JSON - each with self, this, $data, $root as an input and it seems nothing I put there passes a value. In the aspx, I have a textarea with data-bind="value: ko.toJSON($root)" and it does contain the json that I would like to send to the server.

```
    function emailViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    //data
     ...   
    //operations
    ...
    self.saveTemplate = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/emailtemplate/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: ko.toJSON({template: self}),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (result) {
                alert('success');//debug
            },
            error: function () { alert('fail');}//debug

        });
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: How is your `EmailTemplateModel` class and you client side `emailViewModel` look like? Do you know that the property names should match? In theory the `data: ko.toJSON(self),` should work.

Comment: Thanks - they were named the same, but I didn't have all the properties defined in the .net model as they really weren't needed server side. After adding them all, it seems to have solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to specify the dataType as json.  The following works for me (with node/express as the POST handler):

```
...
this.saveTemplate = function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: "/api/emailtemplate",
      type: "POST",
      data: ko.toJSON({ template: this }),
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(result) {
        alert("success");
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("fail");
      }
    }
...
```